# Adding new entries with EntityFrameWork, implementation of many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Goodness! Please explain the behavior EntityFrameWork:

create a model:

```
public class Types
{
     [Key]
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<ControlCheck> ControlChecks {get; set;}
}

public ControlCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Types> CheckTypes {get; set;}
}


public partial class ModeMy : DbContext
{
    public ModeMy()
        : base("name=ConnectionString")
    {
    }

    ...........
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Types>()
            .HasMany<ControlCheck>(cc => cc.ControlChecks)
            .WithMany(c=>c.CheckTypes)
            .Map(cc=>
                {
                    cc.MapLeftKey("ControlCheckType_Id");
                    cc.MapRightKey("ControlChecks_Id");
                    cc.ToTable("ControlCheckTypeControlChecks");
                });
    }
}
```

Next, add entries in the cycle:

```
ModeMy context = new ModeMy(); 
......

while (someCondition)
{
    List<Types> selectedTypes = new List<Types>();
    selectedTypes.Add(context.Types.Where(t=>t.Name.Contains("a")).Single());
    selectedTypes.Add(context.Types.Where(t=>t.Name.Contains("b")).Single());
     selectedTypes.Add(context.Types.Where(t=>t.Name.Contains("c")).Single());
    selectedTypes.Add(context.Types.Where(t=>t.Name.Contains("d")).Single()); 

   ControlCheck newCheck = new ControlCheck 
   {
      Name = "SomeName",
      CheckTypes = selectedTypes 
   }

   context.ControlCheck.Add(newCheck);
   context.SaveChanges();  
}

......
```

When organizing a many-to-many Entity creates an additional table for fixing ties for records, but when Instance of Context create outside the loop add record to ControlCheck table just updated some records in relation Table whereas it should create new record, problem solves when creation Context moves into the loop in this case every new record that add in ControlCheck is reflected in the table relations.
Why this happens? Why I can't use Instance of cantext thats creates outside the loop?

Thanx !